# $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+nx)^m-(1+mx)^n}{\sqrt[m]{1+mx}-\sqrt[n]{1+nx}}$

Tags: limits

Let $n$ and $m$ be distinct positive integers. Evaluate
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+nx)^m-(1+mx)^n}{\sqrt[m]{1+mx}-\sqrt[n]{1+nx}}$$

My attempt, (l'Hopital's rule)

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+nx)^m-(1+mx)^n}{\sqrt[m]{1+mx}-\sqrt[n]{1+nx}}=nm\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+nx)^{m-1}-(1+mx)^{n-1}}{(1+mx)^{1/m-1}-(1+nx)^{1/n-1}}$$

$$=nm\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{n(m-1)(1+nx)^{m-2}-m(n-1)(1+mx)^{n-2}}{(1-m)(1+mx)^{1/m-2}-(1-n)(1+nx)^{1/n-2}}$$

$$=nm\frac{n(m-1)-m(n-1)}{(1-m)-(1-n)}$$

$$=-mn$$

My question would be is there other method to solve this without using l'Hopital's.

**Update**: After writing my attempt here, I realise it can be done by series expansion also.

Comment: Suggestion: you can self-answer your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $u =(1+nx)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ and $v = (1+mx)^{\frac{1}{m}}$. Then, the limit is just:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{u^{mn}-v^{mn}}{v-u}$$
Using the fact that:
$$\frac{u^n-v^n}{u-v} = u^{n-1}+u^{n-2}v +\ldots + v^{n-1}$$
The right-hand side has a total of $n$ terms. Therefore, in the limit above, the given fraction can just be reduced to a total of $mn$ terms and since all of these terms will just approach $1$ as $x \to 0$, it follows that the limit is $-mn$.

Comment: Nice approach here!